# Rails - Wordpress RSS feed listener/notifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some Wordpress blogs that have RSS feeds. 
I want to know if 1 RSS is updated. So that I can run a resque job.That fetches the feeds.

Are there any rubygem that can determinate if a RSS feed is updated?

Like an RSS feed notification gem.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach:

Parse feed to internal memory using https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/feed_parsing and check for the latest message with a cron job (periodically for example every 5 hours) and fetch it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Feedzirra](https://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra). It is able to do what you need:

```
# updating a single feed
updated_feed = Feedzirra::Feed.update(feed)

# an updated feed has the following extra accessors
updated_feed.updated?     # returns true if any of the feed attributes have been modified. will return false if only new entries
updated_feed.new_entries  # a collection of the entry objects that are newer than the latest in the feed before update

# updating multiple feeds. it expects a collection of feed objects
updated_feeds = Feedzirra::Feed.update(feeds.values)
```

Check Feedzirra's readme for other methods available.